Событие при подключении/отключении USB/Jack микрофона
Мне нужно узнать как сделать в программе на C# выполнение какого либо метода если произошло событие отключения либо же подключения микрофона к компьютеру порта USB или Jack. Есть ли какое-то событие которое обрабатывает подключения?
Я пробовал использовать сборку NAudio для захвата подключений аудио-девайсов, но там нет таких определений как, перечисления которые определяют: устройство подключено или отключено, или же какой порт у подключаемого/отключаемого микрофона (USB или Jack).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189538/monitor-microphone-changes
